# PR_SMTP_ADDRESS property error: unknown or cannot be found

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I have Application_ItemSend code in Outlook 2010.

It checks the recipient address and if it isn't one of our domains it will prompt a message asking if you want to send the email externally.

```vb
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim recips As Outlook.Recipients
Dim recip As Outlook.Recipient
Dim pa As Outlook.PropertyAccessor
Dim prompt As String
Dim strMsg As String

Const PR_SMTP_ADDRESS As String = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E"

Set recips = Item.Recipients
For Each recip In recips
    Set pa = recip.PropertyAccessor
            If InStr(LCase(pa.GetProperty(PR_SMTP_ADDRESS)), "@ourdomain1.com.au") = 0 And InStr(LCase(pa.GetProperty(PR_SMTP_ADDRESS)), "@ourdomain2.com.au") = 0 And InStr(LCase(pa.GetProperty(PR_SMTP_ADDRESS)), "@ourdomain3.com.au") = 0 And InStr(LCase(pa.GetProperty(PR_SMTP_ADDRESS)), "@ourdomain4.com.au") = 0 Then
    strMsg = strMsg & "   " & pa.GetProperty(PR_SMTP_ADDRESS) & vbNewLine
    End If
Next
For Each recip In recips
    Set pa = recip.PropertyAccessor
    If InStr(LCase(pa.GetProperty(PR_SMTP_ADDRESS)), "@ourdomain1.com.au") = 0 And InStr(LCase(pa.GetProperty(PR_SMTP_ADDRESS)), "@ourdomain2.com.au") = 0 And InStr(LCase(pa.GetProperty(PR_SMTP_ADDRESS)), "@ourdomain3.com.au") = 0 And InStr(LCase(pa.GetProperty(PR_SMTP_ADDRESS)), "@ourdomain4.com.au") = 0 Then
    prompt = "This email will be sent outside of ourdomains.com.au to:" & vbNewLine & strMsg & "Do you want to proceed?"
    If MsgBox(prompt, vbYesNo + vbExclamation + vbMsgBoxSetForeground, "Check Address") = vbNo Then
            Cancel = True
            Exit Sub
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

This has started throwing an error when sending to some distribution lists.

> "The Property "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E"
> is unknown or cannot be found.

Hitting 'end' to the error pop-up the email is still sent.

From what I have googled, this is because there isn't always a MIME property present so it cannot always be resolved to an SMTP address.

How can I change this so it will not throw the error?

Answer (score 0):

That property may or may not work depending on whether or not the recipient is an Exchange user within your Exchange organization, and whether or not the cached mode is enabled with Exchange.

PR_SMTP_ADDRESS is not available in cached mode. You would use PR_EMS_AB_PROXY_ADDRESSES in cached mode, which is a PT_MV_STRING8 or PT_MV_UNICODE (string array) property.

Finally, you may find the [HowTo: Convert Exchange-based email address into SMTP email address](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2009/05/08/outlook-exchange-email-address-smtp/) article helpful.

Answer (score 0):

PR_SMTP_ADDRESS is not guaranteed to be present. Also if you send to an SMTP recipient, the property will not be present, but PR_EMAIL_ADDRESSS property (exposed by the Recipient.Address property) will contain a regular SMTP address.

Check if PR_ADDRTYPE is "SMTP", and read PR_EMAIL_ADDRESSS. Otherwise try (and handle the error appropriately)  to read the PR_SMTP_ADDRESS property.